# Limits and boundaries of a function

Tags: limits

For homework, we were supposed to find a counterexample to this false statement.

If a function $g$ that is defined on all positive real numbers (zero included) has a real number limit at infinity, then the function $g$ is bounded from both sides. 

I don't think that this is possible; in order for a function not to be bounded, it has to reach infinity at some point over it's domain. It cannot be at infinity, as there is supposed to be a real number limit, it cannot be at zero (because it is supposed to be defined on zero) and it cannot be somewhere else in the function domain, as there would be a discontinuity. Is there an example of a function that satisfies these requirements?

Comment: What's wrong with $g(x) = e^{-x}$ as a counterexample?

Comment: @Gregory The function's domain needs to be only on real positive numbers.

Comment: I believe the statement is actually true for continuous functions on stated domain. Are you sure the problem statement requires the function to be continuous?

Comment: @jmacmanus yes, the question explicitly states that the domain of the function needs to be all positive real numbers including zero

Comment: @ampersander I understand that - I'm asking whether the function itself need be continuous - if not then consider a function $f$ defined piecewise as $f(x) = 1  / x$ for $x > 0$, and $f(0) =0$. This is a counter example to your statement as written.

Comment: @jmacmanus yes, it needs to be continuous

Comment: If the function $g$ is required to be continuous then the statement as written is provably true and no counterexample exists. If not, then the function $f$ as defined above is a valid counterexample.